# Upload email (EML files) to POP server

Tags: imap, upload, pop3, import-mail

I am trying to move my mails from one hosting provider to another.

I have downloaded my emails from my previous hosting provider (which supports IMAP) as EML files using a software. Now I have all my emails as EML files.

My new provider doesn't support IMAP. It supports only SMTP and POP.

How can I upload all emails to my new provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload to a POP3 box - it doesn't support upload, it's a one-way protocol (download only).

The only way you can get your messages back into POP3 is to email them to youself.

The best way is with [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-GB/) and install the [Mail Redirect](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mail-redirect/) addon so you can forward the messages from one account to another without modifying the headers.

Of course, this relies on you still having access to the original IMAP service.

Comment: I still have access to the original IMAP service. Thanks for the information :) Will let you know about the results.

Comment: The addon is not compatible with latest version of Thunderbird :( Is there another such way to forward without modifying header?

Comment: damn, that sucks, sorry.  I can't see any other add-on at the moment to do it, but maybe another client has the option?  I'm googling but not having much luck at the moment.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded an older version of thunderbird. Redirected emails :)