# Reupload emails to POP inbox

Tags: email, gnome, pop3, evolution

The Evolution mail client has by default deleted all of my messages from my POP inbox. As I own multiple devices this is a huge inconvenience.

The messages are now stored locally under `~/.local/share/evolution/mail/local/cur` in plain text files.

How can I revert this destructive operation? Is there any way to un-delete the emails? I have seen a few answers ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/3810798/1893275 [Upload email (EML files) to POP server](https://superuser.com/questions/275063/upload-email-eml-files-to-pop-server) ) mentioning mailing the messages to myself, but the procedure was not more closely described.

Comment: POP3 is purely for retrieval. It is entirely impossible to upload mails using POP3. If you’re using multiple devices, you really should be using IMAP or a similar method to access your mailboxes.

Comment: The client doesn't delete the mails usually, the POP server deletes them after at least one device received each one [usually with a settable delay, up to one month]. Once it's gone from a POP3 server, than unless you have access to any server backups, it's gone.

Comment: @DanielB - "should be using IMAP" ... not necessarily. It depends where you consider the 'master' to be. Personally I consider it to be 'my desktop' & don't want reams of stuff syncing between devices I'm not remotely interested in 8/10 emails I receive.

Comment: It’s actually the client deleting mail explicitly using the `DELE` POP3 command. It can of course choose not to. // I don’t see how POP3 is about any master or whatnot, but whatever.

Comment: All it is, is a delivery system. If you want to save your mail, you must save it locally. For that you want one central 'master', so mails received at any other device can be ephemeral, deleted to keep space requirements down - phones etc. If you delete your master [& have no backup], you end up in the situation the OP is in... stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your email account in evolution as IMAP account and then you should be able to copy messages from "POP3" account to "IMAP" account.